# Get column value if it changed from previous (MS SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Lets Assume I have following data in table (Table1)

```
id       Time
1        15/06/2012 8:03:43 PM 
1        15/06/2012 8:03:48 PM 
1        15/06/2012 8:03:53 PM
1        15/06/2012 8:03:58 PM     
2        15/06/2012 8:04:03 PM 
2        15/06/2012 8:04:08 PM
3        15/06/2012 8:04:13 PM 
3        15/06/2012 8:04:18 PM
3        15/06/2012 8:04:23 PM
2        15/06/2012 8:04:03 PM 
2        15/06/2012 8:04:03 PM
```

can i get rows where column value has changed (only for column id). I want the following result

```
 id    time
-----  -----------------------
1      2012-06-15 20:03:43.000
2      2012-06-15 20:04:03.000
3      2012-06-15 20:04:13.000
2      2012-06-15 20:04:03.000
```

Comment: Table order is undefined. You need some kind of sequential column to do this.

Comment: As your Time-column is not sorted, I can see no sort order. The second occurence of "2" is not detectable without a sort order. What do you need?

Answer (score 1):

This clearly doesn't answer your question, since you are using SQL Server 2008, but, for other users, I wanted to add an example of a solution using the lag function in Sql Server 2012 and higher.

```
select id,[time] from ( 
    select 
        *,
        lag(id,1) over (order by (select 'constant')) as previousId
    from table1
) t 
where id <> previousId or previousId is null
```

As noted elsewhere, you should have a column that you can sort on and replace the `(select 'constant')` with that column.  i.e. `order by insertDate`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the intention is to sort the data by time (which is not exactly how your data is shown), then you can do this.  In SQL Server 2012+, you would use `lag()`.  In earlier versions, you can  use `outer apply` for the same effect:

```
select t.*
from table1 t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from table1 t2
      where t2.time < t.time
      order by t2.time desc
     ) tprev
where tprev.id is null or tprev.id <> t.id;
```

Of course, if another column specifies the ordering, then you can use that instead of `time`.